# How to determine Audio file path and availability in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: vba, scripting, audio, powerpoint

I am duplicating with minor date changes, slideshows created by another user, who constantly forgets to embed audio, but links it instead.

Is there some simple way to determine whether audio is embedded or linked, and what the source file path is, if it is linked? If I could run a macro to just determine this it would help enormously.

Not sure how to approach this, but individually opening dozens of files to determine audio is there defeats everything else that is scripted in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I would do it:

```
Sub DetermineAudioLinks()
Dim p As Presentation: Set p = ActivePresentation
Dim s As Slide
Dim sh As Shape

For Each s In p.Slides
    For Each sh In s.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoMedia Then
            If sh.MediaType = ppMediaTypeSound Then
                Debug.Print "Slide " & s.SlideNumber & ":" ; sh.Name
                If sh.MediaFormat.IsLinked Then
                    Debug.Print vbTab & "Is Linked: True"
                    Debug.Print vbTab & sh.LinkFormat.SourceFullName
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Note the the `MediaFormat` property above is PowerPoint 2010 only - it won't work with earlier versions of PowerPoint.

Comment: I forgotten I had asked about the original file path. I need to determine the path of the file if at all possible

Comment: @datatoo: yeah, the `SourceFullName` above will give you the path to the file.

Comment: I was getting an error on the If sh.MediaFormat.IsLinked line. not sure why, but not now.